# PostgreSQL Record Reordering using Update with a Sub-Select

Tags: postgresql

I found this solution on the SQL Server forum on how to reorder records in a table.

```
UPDATE SomeTable
SET rankcol = SubQuery.Sort_Order
FROM
    (
    SELECT IDCol, Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY ValueCOL) as SORT_ORDER
    FROM SomeTable
    ) SubQuery
INNER JOIN SomeTable ON
SubQuery.IDCol = SomeTable.IDCol
```

When I try doing the same on PostgreSQL, I get an error message -

ERROR:  table name "sometable" specified more than once

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Reordering rows and setting the value in a column (which is what this query apparently tries to do) are two different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don`t need to explicitly join SomeTable, how cool is that? :)

```
UPDATE SomeTable
SET rankcol = SubQuery.Sort_Order
FROM
    (
    SELECT IDCol, Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY ValueCOL) as SORT_ORDER
    FROM SomeTable
    ) SubQuery
where SubQuery.IDCol = SomeTable.IDCol
```

remark: Postgres is case insensitive, better use lower-case, like `row_number`, `sort_order`, `id_col` , etc.