# PostgreSQL value incrementation

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

Given a table `cc_playlist` with 4 row/records where `id_key` is the primary key that auto increments, and `track_id`, `track_position` and `playlist_id`:

```
+--------+----------+----------------+-------------+
| id_key | track_id | track_position | playlist_id |
+--------+----------+----------------+-------------+
|     23 |        3 |              0 |           1 |
|    223 |       23 |              1 |           1 |
|    343 |       45 |              2 |           1 |
|    344 |       32 |              3 |           1 |
+--------+----------+----------------+-------------+
```

Problem:
When I wish to add a new record, e.g. `track_id = 777` ,`track_position=2`, `playlist_id =1`, I want it to place the new record and push the rest of the records down, as long as it is in the same `playlist_id`.

```
    +--------+----------+----------------+-------------+
    | id_key | track_id | track_position | playlist_id |
    +--------+----------+----------------+-------------+
    |     23 |        3 |              0 |           1 |
    |    223 |       23 |              1 |           1 |
 -->|    345 |      777 |              2 |           1 |
    |    343 |       45 |              3 |           1 |
    |    344 |       32 |              4 |           1 |
    +--------+----------+----------------+-------------+
```

NOTE: I am doing this in php, If it can't be done in Postgres.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'push the rest of the records down'? Nothing about the other records seems to have changed.

Comment: But what is the point of this? Can't you just `ORDER BY track_position` in your query? I'm asking because AFAIK with auto-increment it'd either very hard or impossible to do.

Comment: Aha! see my *award winning* answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14092775/905902

Comment: Interesting solution however I cannot add a new field to the database.

Comment: my gut feeling is that the problem is not solvable without an extra state-variable per row. please prove me wrong.

Comment: :), i'm not a pro at programming.  I am learning sql/php/shell by trying to solve my current problem. The bigger picture is that the database (application) does not belong to me, just trying to add functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is a query like this before you insert the new record:

```
update cc_playlist
    set track_position = track_position + 1
    where playlist_id = YOURPLAYLISTID and track_position > YOURTRACKPOSITION;
```

Note you'll need to do something similar for `delete`, when you remove a track.

Also, you can set this up as an update trigger in the database, so the database does this automatically.  Or, wrap the insert in a stored procedure, and do both the insert and the update there.

Comment: that is exactly what i have ended up doing, bacically after the incrementation i do the insert, and the same thing in reverse to remove track. BTW thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should just insert the new row with the appropriate **track_position** and order by **track_position** when querying the table (bear with me).

The reason is because PostgreSQL stores tables as unordered heaps. This means that every time you insert a row on a table it gets appended (ie, inserted at the end) to the file holding the table's contents.

There's a way to reorganize a table according to an index ([postgresql cluster](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-cluster.html)). I'm including this in case you want to user it for testing purposed but I totally advice against doing this. That being said, you would create an index on the table using **playlist_id, track_id** as the index key and then use the cluster command.

I also think is a bad idea doing this in php, as this behavior clearle belongs in PostgreSQL.

I know this is not an actual answer to your question, but maybe it helps

To summarize:

- Just insert the row and order when querying
- Do this in PostgreSQL, not in php
- Don't use cluster

Comment: What's the typo? I don't see the difference.

Comment: :), i did not number the track position properly ( well it is fixed now)

Comment: Oh, I see. Wow, what a typo haha. Glad to hear it's fixed