# Database constraint checking if values (from different rows) are in consecutive order

Tags: database, postgresql, constraints

I'm setting up a PostgreSQL database, and want to create a constraint for checking if values (from different rows in a single table) are consecutive.

The table looks like this:

```
+-------------+---------+-------+
| waypoint_id | path_id | order |
+-------------+---------+-------+
|          89 |       1 |     1 |
|          16 |       1 |     2 |
|          17 |       1 |     3 |
|          19 |       1 |     4 |
|           4 |       1 |     5 |
|          75 |       2 |     1 |
|          28 |       2 |     2 |
|           2 |       2 |     3 |
+-------------+---------+-------+
```

It's a table for storing the order of waypoints of a certain path.

- The **waypoint_id** is a ForeignKey to a table where the coordinates of the
  waypoints are stored.
- The **path_id** is a ForeignKey to a table where info about
  the path is stored (what type of path etc).
- The **order** is an integer that stores the order of the waypoints in a specific path.
- The PrimaryKey is a composite of all 3 columns.

The constraint has to check if the values in the order column (with equal path_id) are consecutive.

This is an **INVALID** example: (the order is not consecutive because the 3 is missing)

```
+-------------+---------+-------+
| waypoint_id | path_id | order |
+-------------+---------+-------+
|          21 |       1 |     1 |
|          29 |       1 |     2 |
|         104 |       1 |     4 |
+-------------+---------+-------+
```

I expect a constraint to **not** allow the INSERT of this row:

```
 |         104 |       1 |     4 |
```

Please show me examples of solutions for similar problems or point me to documentation on how to do his.

Comment: Note: your model allows a waypoint to occur more than once on a path, creating cycles. Do you want to allow cycles? Second: `order` is a reserved word; better not use it as a columnname. Third: *why* does the `order`need to be consecutive? IMO it only needs to be *orderable*

Comment: Yes I want to allow a waypoint to occur multiple times. Second: thanks, I will change that. Third: I am not sure what orderable means exactly (and Google doesn't tell me either). The order always starts at 1 and counts up from there, without skipping numbers. Is this orderable? If not, what is orderable exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b67be9527e86fd444d158f9ab93bf600

For the impatient:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION consecutive_check()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    IF NEW."order" = 1 OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_table WHERE path_id = NEW.path_id AND "order" = (NEW."order" - 1)) THEN
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;

    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Previous waypoint not available for path_id = %', NEW.path_id;
END;
$function$;

CREATE TRIGGER no_holes_path
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON my_table
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE consecutive_check()
;
```

**WARNING**: This will result in the table being queried, so you **must** have an index over `path_id` and `order` and you **must** be aware of the fact that this solution will not scale well.

Answer (score 0):

- The candidate key for this table is `(track_id, "order")`; the `waypoint_id` doesnot need tobe included.
- (you could add an extra unique constraint on `(track_id, waypoint_id)`to prevent points to be visited twice on a single track)
- the *gapless* constraint is notneeded, you only need order and (per track) uniqueness on `order`
- `ORDER` is a keyword; better avoid it as an identifier.

---

```
CREATE TABLE tracks
        (track_id INTEGER NOT NULL
        , step INTEGER NOT NULL
        , waypoint_id INTEGER -- REFERENCES waypoints(id)
        , PRIMARY KEY (track_id,step)
        );

INSERT INTO tracks(track_id, step, waypoint_id)VALUES
(1,1,89) , (1,2,16) , (1,4,17), (1,5,19), (1,6,4)       -- mind the gap!
, (2,11,75) , (2,22,28) , (2,44,2)                      -- Large gaps!
        ;

CREATE VIEW tracks_ordered AS
SELECT track_id
        , rank() OVER (PARTITION BY track_id ORDER BY step) AS "Order!"
        , waypoint_id
FROM tracks;

SELECT *FROM tracks_ordered;
```

---

Result:

---

```
 track_id | Order! | waypoint_id 
----------+--------+-------------
        1 |      1 |          89
        1 |      2 |          16
        1 |      3 |          17
        1 |      4 |          19
        1 |      5 |           4
        2 |      1 |          75
        2 |      2 |          28
        2 |      3 |           2
(8 rows)
```

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085258/how-do-i-get-a-column-with-consecutive-increasing-numbers-without-having-any-n/14092775#14092775 for bad advice